# Override toString efficiently with Char[] Array

Tags: java, arrays, oop, tostring

I'm creating a class with a `char[]` array as the only instance variable. I have to use a constructor and accesor methods and such but the difficult part is creating an efficient `toString()` method.

Right now, I've initialized the array as:
`private char[] tune = new char[5];`

My toString() method looks like this:

```
public String toString() {
        return notes[0] + " " + notes[1] + " " + notes[2] + " " + notes[3] + " " + notes[4];
    }
```

**My question is:** Is there a more efficient method of printing this. I thought of using a for loop, as shown below:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= tune.length; i++) {
            return tune[i] + " ";
        }
```

but I assume that would return tune[0] and just stop.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What's the simplest way to print a Java array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/409784/whats-the-simplest-way-to-print-a-java-array). Basically just `return Arrays.toString(notes)`.

Comment: What's inefficient about concatenating the elements in your first snippet?

Comment: Create a string outside loop then you can add `tune[i] + " "` in a string in every iteration of loop.

Comment: @takendarkk output of that would be different though

Comment: @eis I guess you are correct - I'm not sure if the exact output format OP showed is required or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to override the `toString()` method, use a `StringBuilder` which is initialized outside the loop.

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (char ch : array) { // you used both notes and tune arrays in your examples,
  // so I'm just going to use "array" as the variable name as an example
    sb.append(ch);
    sb.append(" ");
  }
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Note that this will cause an extra space at the end, if this is not wanted, use this instead:

```
public String toString() {
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length - 1; i++) { // adds a space after every element
  // except for the last one, hence "i < array.length - 1"
    sb.append(array[i] + " ");
  }
  sb.append(array[array.length - 1]); // adds only the last element and no space
  // after
  return sb.toString();
}
```

Hope this is easy to understand!

NOTE - Java can already convert the `char[]` to string, but I'm assuming you want to change the way it does that.

Comment: if you're already using stringbuilder, why not use `sb.append(ch); sb.append(" ");` - there's little point in using `ch + " "` if you're using stringbuilder

Answer (score 0):

Arrays already have built in methods to print out the entire Array. (Not the case for ArrayLists).

If you look in the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/14/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Arrays.html) for Arrays, you can see that there is a function called `Arrays.toString()`

Here is an example of how you can use it.
String[] array = new String[] {"a","b","c"};

```
// Print out the Array
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(array));

// Output
[a,b,c]
```

If you would like to print out an array from index a to index b, then using a `for...` loop would be better.